# Edit size of component in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, resize, layout-manager, grid-layout

Currently, I have a set of `JLabel` with preferred size in a `GridLayout`. This grid layout is in a `JScrollPane` for having a scroll Bar.

I would like to manage to increase and decrease the size of this label but I don't know how to do this. It is possible to retrieve the size of components of grid layout?

Here it is:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXtpV.png)

And my currently code : https://github.com/SebGonzalez/2DLevelEditor
GridLayout as used in IHM/PanelCreation

Comment: Would be easier to visualise this with a screenshot but it sounds like you want to use a 'GridBagLayout'. Please post your code as a minimum but runnable example so we can help.

Comment: I add a screen and my code ;)

Comment: You'll be lucky if someone is going to search through your entire codebase for the project. It's best to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help faster.

Comment: @petehallw Great suggestion. A tip: A shortcut for the MCVE is to put `[mcve]` in a comment. It automatically expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

> I have a set of JLabel with PreferredSide in a gridLayout.

Don't use `setPreferredSize()` on a components. Each component will determine its own preferred size.

> I would like to manage to increase and decrease the size of this JLabel but i don't know how to do this

You just use the `setText(...)` method and the label will recalculated its own size.

Or, if you want extra space on the label then you can use an `EmptyBorder` on the label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Comment: The probleme is that without setPreferredSize() JLabel are very little because I use a JScrollPane.

Comment: @Sebastien and what did part 2 of my answer suggest you can do?

Comment: If i use EmptyBorder how i can reduce size of JLabel with button ? Reduce border ? But i can't access to JLabel by GridLayout no ?

Comment: @Sebastien, I have no idea what you are asking. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates what you have tried and explain what the current problem is with your solution.